# Angular - error TS2322: Type '{ id: number; name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<any> | null | undefined'

Tags: angular

In my Angular-12, I have my api JSON endpoint as:

```js
{
  "message": "Categories Successfully Retrieved.",
  "error": false,
  "code": 200,
  "results": {
    "categories": [{
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Computer",
      "parent_id": null,
      "child": [{
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Central Processing Unit",
          "parent_id": 2,
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "Hard Disc",
          "parent_id": 2,
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
}
```

Service:

```
public getCategories(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(this.api.baseURL + 'categories/list', this.httpOptions);
}
```

Then I have this interface:

```
export interface ICategory {
  id?: number;
  name: string;
  parent_id?: number;
  child?: {id:number,name:string};
}
```

Component:

```js
data = [];
allCategoryList: any[] = [];
category!: ICategory;
isLoading = false;
isSubmitted = false;

constructor(
  private fb: FormBuilder,
  private categoryService: CategoryService,
  private router: Router,
  private store: Store < AppState > ,
) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.isLoading = true;
  this.loadCategory();
  this.loadDatatable();
}

loadCategory() {
  this.categoryService.getCategories().subscribe(
    data => {
      this.allCategoryList = data.results.categories;
    },
    error => {
      this.store.dispatch(loadErrorMessagesSuccess(error));
      this.isLoading = false;
    }
  );
}

viewCategoryModal(row: any) {
  this.category = row;
}
```

HTML:

I am trying to use the list below to display the detail of each row:

```
<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" (click)="editCategoryModal(row)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editCategoryModal">
                Edit
</a>
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="viewCategoryModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"> Category Details</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body" *ngIf="category != undefined">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              Category: <strong>{{ Category.name || 'N/A' }}</strong>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="row">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th style="width: 100%">Contract</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody *ngIf="category.child != undefined">
                <tr *ngFor="let subcategory of category.child">
                  <td>{{subcategory.name}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr *ngIf="!category.child">
                  <td colspan="4" class="text-center">
                    <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-lg align-center"></span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="hide()">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Parent Category will have many child subcategory. So when user clicks the parent category detail row, it suppose to display the modal for the detail parent category and all it's child categories, but I got this error:

> error TS2322: Type '{ id: number; name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable | null | undefined'.

and it highlights of  in:

> 

How do I get this resolved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help to solve your problem?

IPlace.ts:

```js
export interface IPlace {
  id:number,
  name:string
}
```

ICategory.ts:

```js
import { Place } from './Place'

export interface ICategory {
  id?: number;
  name: string;
  parent_id?: number;
  child?: IPlace[];
}
```

Comment: If this doesn't help you, I'm willing to take another look. If you could make a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) that would make it easyer for us to help.